# Female equivalent of 'son' to call kids

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

From the perspective of semantics, the female equivalent of *son* obviously is *daughter.*

But here's my question: It seems to be some kind of cliché that some people (Priests, wise men, or even real fathers)  refer to young boys by "son" when speaking directly to them: e.g., "Son, you know that..."

Simply putting it in the correct female form "Daughter, you know that..." feels wrong, somehow. How would a person often calling young boys "son" call young girls?

What about - Again, we're talking about some kinds of stereotyped clichés here - a priest with an adopted daugther? I could definitely imagine him calling an adopted son *son*, while I don't know what such a person would call a daugther.

Asking because I am currently practicing my English by writing a small story.

Comment: Have you consider "child"?

Comment: Certainly "daughter" is used in many US sub-cultures, but a slightly more common alternative is "child".  "Son" has a special status because of the emphasis (mistakenly?) placed on father-son "bonding".

Comment: Good question. The closest thing I can think of in anything like English smacks rather of the British Isles and especially some of the less English parts thereof: my lass. The (modern) Greeks hit this nail on the head with κορίτσι μου.

Comment: _Priests_ and some _wise men_ (are they disjoint sets?) would use 'Daughter', but not _whatever really_. People from Yorkshire (probably _very wise men_ would use 'Eh, lass ...'.

Comment: From a usage standpoint, the (not exactly) parallel term is 'miss'.

Comment: @ashkan Yes, and while it does sound like a nice possibility, I believe that it is not specific enough. I honestly could not imagine some persons calling their sons "child" instead of "son".

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly! The word I am looking for would be the one used for "parent-daughter" bonding instead of "father-son" bonding. And simply "daugther" seems a little out of place.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Priests* and *wise men* are not disjoint sets, I simply used them to illustrate my example a little better. The question also obviously relies on some stereotypes. How about people outside of Yorkshire? US?

Comment: @JEL It does sound a little formal, though. Like the start of a sentence the parent would use to scold his/her daugther.

Comment: I think that parents calling their child "daughter" is something that **should** happen: a parent calling their male child "son" feels nice for both parties and it's a shame for the girls to miss out on this.  I suspect it's common in many other languages.  I'd recommend just doing it, and being part of a movement.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Of course, one reason why "son" has more currency that "daughter" (aside from the sexism issue) is that "son" is a shorter word, and shorter words tend to be preferred for such uses.

Comment: I think there's a lot of lee-way, depending on the character of your fictional speaker.  My first mother in law referred to her daughter as "daughter" and me, her son in law, as "my dear".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person speaking to the girl is not related, a common thing would be to say "young lady, you know that..."

If the speaker is her father, "young lady" may seem too formal. Her dad would probably just call her by her first name, as in "Jenny, you know that..."

This is, of course, assuming the girl is, in fact, a young lady. Usually, when someone refers to another male as "son", that male is a young man or boy. So, that is why I am saying that "young lady" would work for a female here.

Comment: Right, "young lady" definitely seems like a good possibility. But also, as you already said, a little too formal for an actual parent-daughter relationship.

Comment: Young lady is usually used in a "jokingly formal" way, and often used as part of a mild (again often semi-serious) rebuke, like "Don't you talk to me like that, young lady!" .  The same rules apply for "Young man" for male children.

Answer (score 2):

***Lass*** is defined by [Meriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lass) as:

> *a girl or young woman*

This term could be substituted with *son*.

> *Lass*, you know not to chew with your mouth open.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that word. How widely is it used?

Comment: "Lass" is widely used in the north-east of England, as the female counterpart of "lad".   The similar "Lassie" (and "laddie") is widely used in Scotland (and Ireland I think).  In the north east of England "lass" can also mean "girlfriend".  I'd say that most British people are familar with the words even if they don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

If the father is talking to his daughter, he would probably say "Honey, that is not how you treat your brother."
If a man is speaking to a girl that is not related to him, I guess Cliff's answer above is correct, "Young lady, that is not how you treat your mother."

Comment: A man using "honey" to address an unrelated female would likely be considered to be "improper".

Comment: In my answer i clearly wrote "..the father talking to her daughter.."

Comment: Honey is American English: in this context, it is rare in British English.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest and least condescending equivalent is **Dear** or **My Dear**. It is more casual than **Young Lady**, but perhaps less cliche, which was one of the required fields.

*An affectionate or friendly form of address.*

It adds an immediate connection, and has the same disarming effect that using **Son** in the way that you described does.

Comment: Yes, that definitely also sounds like a good possiblity. I fear that it sounds a little bit too "mature", though - As in, something a parent would call his/her spouse, or an already grown up daugther. I may be wrong though, obviously. What do you think?

Comment: Well when I've heard it used, it is a spouse's term of endearment second, and a broad term for females first. I use it frequently myself when speaking to strangers, though I use 'my friend' as the male counterpart, rather than 'son,' because I myself am relatively young. 'Young Lady' may be the closest equivalent that mirrors the condescension aspect in 'son,' but 'dear' is much more commonly used I find.

Answer (score 0):

And then there was Miss Jean Brodie, who, in her prime, simply addressed them as "Little girls," which today may sound offensive. Sage advice, given by someone in a position of authority to a female charge, most comfortably begins with "My dear..." It is the equivalent of "son."

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not correct but where I live in Scotland we say *Hen* instead of *Son* when speaking to our daughters. I know a lot of people around the world will scoff at the idea. It really is used as a female version of *Son*. I sometimes call my boys *Son* and daughter *Hen*, but then again I often use their names instead. I think its just regional slang more than anything else.